# Can the result of `fun :: (SomeTypeClass a) => Maybe a -> Result` change if I pass differently typed values of `Nothing`?

Tags: haskell

Pretty much the headline, but let's elaborate:

Assume I have some type class `SomeTypeClass` and different types `A`, `B`, `C` which each have an instance for it.

Let's further assume I have a function

```
fun :: (SomeTypeClass a) => Maybe a -> Result
```

for some type constant `Result`.

Can the expressions

1. `fun (Nothing :: Maybe A)`
2. `fun (Nothing :: Maybe B)`
3. `fun (Nothing :: Maybe C)`

yield different results somehow?

(Maybe by some compiler extension to provide different implementations for `fun` depending on the argument type or something.)

Comment: You can specify optimizations for for instance the `A` type: https://www.stackbuilders.com/tutorials/haskell/ghc-optimization-and-fusion/

Comment: If you could provide some sample code showing differing results, that would be totally an anwser. If I read the linked article correctly, specializing is not a "threat" here, but rewrite rules are.

Comment: Of course; here is such a function: `typeRep :: Typeable a => Maybe a -> TypeRep`

Comment: No compiler extensions are necessary for providing different implementations of a class based on types. That's the whole point of classes. They dispatch based on compile-time type, not a run-time tag. (There are some blurry cases regarding polymorphic recursion, but even then the type information was worked out piecewise at compile-time.)

Comment: Woa, just noticed, that *facepalm*. Sorry for the noise question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, with `Result` = `String` and `SomeTypeClass a` = `(Monoid a, Show a)`:

```
import Data.Foldable
doSomething :: (Show a, Monoid a) => Maybe a -> String
doSomething = show . fold

doSomething (Nothing :: Maybe String) == "\"\""
doSomething (Nothing :: Maybe [Int] == "[]"
doSomething (Nothing :: Maybe (Product Int)) == "Product {getProduct=1}"
doSomething (Nothing :: Maybe (Sum Int)) == "Sum {getSum=0}"
```

Not the only example of course, but probably the simplest (also, something which is at least similar to something you might encounter in real code).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I could come up with to achieve this is the following hack:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

data A = A
data B = B

class SomeClass a where
  doSomething :: a -> String

instance SomeClass A where
  doSomething _ = "always a"

instance SomeClass B where
  doSomething _ = "always b"

instance SomeClass a => SomeClass (Maybe a) where
  doSomething (Just x) = doSomething x
  doSomething Nothing = doSomething (undefined :: a)

main = print (doSomething (Nothing :: Maybe A), doSomething (Nothing :: Maybe B), doSomething (Just A))
```

You can get around the ugly `undefined` by using a `data Proxy a = Proxy` data type. I'm not sure how useful this is in practice as you cannot inspect the input in the instances for `A` and `B`.

Edit: here's the proxied version where you can inspect the inputs when they are `Just a`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

data A = A Int
data B = B Int

data Proxy a = Proxy

class SomeClass a where
  doSomething :: a -> String

instance SomeClass A where
  doSomething (A x) = "always A with " ++ show x

instance SomeClass B where
  doSomething (B x) = "always B with " ++ show x

instance SomeClass (Proxy A) where
    doSomething Proxy = "proxy A(Nothing)"

instance SomeClass (Proxy B) where
    doSomething Proxy = "proxy B(Nothing)"

instance (SomeClass a, SomeClass (Proxy a)) => SomeClass (Maybe a) where
  doSomething (Just x) = doSomething x
  doSomething Nothing = doSomething (Proxy :: Proxy a)

main = print (doSomething (Nothing :: Maybe A), doSomething (Nothing :: Maybe B), doSomething (Just $ A 2))
```

It feels even more like a hack though(`UndecidableInstances` yikes)

Comment: Those are interesting and enlightening examples. They aren't answers to my question though, as `:t doSomething` yields `doSomething :: SomeClass a  => a -> String`, which isn't the type `SomeClass a => Maybe a -> String` which would be the function I asked for in your example.

Comment: To explain, why I am nitpicking here: I want to know, if I see that signature in a library, If I have to worry about, which type of Nothing I do pass in.

Comment: I see, I slightly misunderstood your question. I'll try to update the examples.

Answer (score 1):

For reference the most basic example, I found:

```
module TestNothings where

class SomeClass a where
    doSomething :: Maybe a -> Int

newtype A = A Int deriving (Eq, Show)
newtype B = B Int deriving (Eq, Show)
newtype C = C Int deriving (Eq, Show)

instance SomeClass A where
    doSomething (Just (A i)) = i
    doSomething Nothing = 0

instance SomeClass B where
    doSomething (Just (B i)) = i
    doSomething Nothing = 1

instance SomeClass C where
    doSomething (Just (C i)) = i
    doSomething Nothing = 2
```

Comment: It didn't occurred to me, until now, that I don't need to always have signatures like `a -> Something` in a type class, but I can bury the type `a` which will need to have an instance for the type class in some different types like in `Maybe a -> Something`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding another typeclass helper can avoid the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension can be avoided if we introduce another typeclass helper with the default `fun` implementation that calls ad-hoc "overloaded" `Nothing` cases which use their argument for type deducing only:

```
type Result = String

data A = A
data B = B

class SomeClass a where
    foo :: a -> Result

instance SomeClass A where
    foo _ = "A"

instance SomeClass B where
    foo _ = "B"

class SomeClass a => Fun a where
    fun :: Maybe a -> Result
    fun (Just a) = foo a
    fun a = funNothing a

    funNothing :: Maybe a -> Result

instance Fun A where
    funNothing _ = "No A"

instance Fun B where
    funNothing _ = "No B"

main = do
    putStrLn $ fun (Just A)
    putStrLn $ fun (Just B)
    putStrLn $ fun (Nothing :: Maybe A)
    putStrLn $ fun (Nothing :: Maybe B)
```

When a new type is added, fun can be easily extended with a new `Fun` instance.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I understand it the following way:

To implement a function `fun` like this, you need ad-hoc polymorphism, i.e. you need different implementations of `fun` for different input types. Without the possibility to get an `a` of the correct type out of `Nothing` (i.e. thin air), the answer would be **no**.

However, if your type class `SomeTypeClass` has a function:

```
f :: Maybe a -> Result
```

then `fun` can be identical to `f`:

```
fun = f
```

Now you have ad-hoc polymorphism by implementing different versions of `f` in your instances. I.e. the answer is **yes**, but you have to implement the relevant parts of your problem in the type class.